# IV Regression - First Stage Observations Higher than Second Stage

Tags: instrumental-variables

This is a very basic question, but I need help. Imagine I have a dataset for variables y, x, and z. I am running an instrumental variable regression such that y is my main outcome variable. So I am trying to estimate the following regressions.

$$y=β_{0}+β_{1}x+e$$

$$x=α_{0}+α_{1}z+u$$

I have N observations. K observations contain values for y, z and x. N-K observations contain values only for x and z, with y values being reported as NA. K > N - K so that I have more complete than incomplete observations in the data.

My question is: should I run the first stage regression with all N observations and THEN run the main equation with only K fitted values? Or should I drop the incomplete N - K observations to begin with and just focus on K complete observations for the first and second stages? Would this at all affect the way I calculate standard errors?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not be running IV with two steps literally; the IV estimator in the just identified case has a closed form $\beta_{IV} = (Z^{\prime} X)^{-1} Z^\prime y$, which of course in your case reduces to $\frac{\sum_i z_i y_i}{\sum_i z_i x_i}$. This means you would only be using the observations where you have no missing data for the entire vector $(y_i,x_i,z_i)$

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!